# unfortunately your browser is not supported. please try another one

Tags: frontend-error

I just went live this morning and got that message suddenly when opening the website. It appears every time you go to another page. Clients are getting annoyed by it. Does any of you have a clue of why we are receiving this pop-up message?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Pablo.

Comment: Try doing a code base search for this error msg (and any third party js file that you have link to).

Comment: Must be specific to your installation, cannot find "browser is not supported" by running grep on a 1.9.2.3 installation.

Answer (score 2):

The message comes from `/js/braintree/braintree-utils.js` when using Older browser version.

Following Code in `/js/braintree/braintree-utils.js` generates these alert messages:

```
onUnsupported: function (obj) {
                alert(unsupported);
                if (typeof onCancel === 'function') {
                    onCancel();
                } 
            },
```

You can upgrade your browser to get rid of the message.